# "Float" images upwards with CSS

Tags: html, css, image, pinterest

I'm trying to make a Pinterest-like gallery for my portfolio. Nothing too fancy, just displaying images that are found in a folder by some simple PHP. I will attach a lightbox (or something like it) later.

For now, I have trouble with letting the images "float" upwards against the other pictures. In some magical way, the two images in the top right do it, but the other ones do not.
[image]

You can see it live [here](http://rvervuurt.com/upload/).
Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/%5C), but it doesn't show the images.

Is there some easy way to do it? Or do I really need to start using some kind of jQuery-plugin for this?
Thanks!

Comment: Pinterest uses absolute positioning. Is your goal/requirement to have the images wind up in the right place with CSS alone with no JavaScript? In other words, a solution that doesn't require calculating the position of each image, or using columns and programmatically deciding which column to place each image in?

Comment: Sammaye brings up a good point: *is the user allowed to reorder the items in the page*? I was oblivious to that pinterest functionality and was looking at the layout only (which imo seems reasonable for a portfolio)

Comment: What about flexible box layout in CSS3? Can that provide this sort of layout? (aside from not being supported in IE9 and earlier)

Comment: It not working on a stable IE is quite a sacrifice..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

http://masonry.desandro.com/

Masonry is a good grid arranging JQuery plugin. Probably one the best out there.

I personally have not used it however friends of mine have with good results saying that:

- It is customisable
- It is quite lightweight for what it does
- It is fast

Unfortunately it is not exactly the fastest thing in the known universe since it uses JQuery (which is already a relatively slow Library, or framework as its starting to get) and puts a CPU intensive calculation on top. As such it is not as fast as a CSS hack but whether Masonry is the best choice or not depends on exactly what you need it for which has been left out in this question.

If you are building a simple portfolio type thing then a CSS hack is the best method but if your building something further then this might be the one your looking for.

Unfortunately due to patchy standards across browsers like IE you will find producing this layout without considerable resources placed client side (such as image resizing for very large images that could have been cropped server side) difficult.

o.v. and ThinkingStiff do have answers and if you were to standard resize every image that comes into your site to a particular size and use caching method available for the layout you could easily get away with a CSS hack for something simple like a photo page or a portfolio.

Comment: Why have people been down voting this? It does what he askes

Comment: -1, the solution focuses on nice shuffle effects that conceal original content flash. Masonry is nice, but it focuses on solutions for content with variable width - this is not the case for OP and there are more straightforward ways to deal with it.

Comment: Well at least some one had the courtesy to say why, thank you for doing so.

Comment: Using Masonry may be the best solution, but a link by itself is not an answer (http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231/172756). Add some code. At least explain what Masonry is. Your edit about browser support is a start.

Comment: @ThinkingStiff I agree, and most of my answers are well put. Though I thought the link explained it all but now that you have explained the linkrot badness I have edited my answer to add some content.

Comment: This was what I needed. It works as I need, even in IE. Thanks! You can see it live here: http://www.rvervuurt.com/upload Note: It's not working properly and having way too big images, but it's just to test the system :) As a reaction on Sammaye's edit: The CSS hack did not work on IE, so I think your suggestion is the right solution.

Comment: Not even o.v's CSS hack? weird it is using standard CSS. Yea I have heard Masonry takes some tweaking and fiddling to get it right.

Answer (score 6):

You can do this with CSS3 `column-count`, assuming you at least have a single containing element. This method has the advantage of changing layout easily (for a mobile device, for example) by simply adding a class.

Output:

[image]

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ThinkingStiff/rS95S/

CSS:

```css
#container {
    column-count: 3;
    column-fill: balance;
    column-gap: 10px;
    width: 330px;
}

.image { 
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    width: 100px;
}
```

HTML:

```html
<div id="container">
<img class="image" src="http://farm1.staticflickr.com/205/494701000_744cc3a83a_z.jpg" />
<img class="image" src="http://farm5.staticflickr.com/4028/4287569889_f6a4fca31b_z.jpg" />
<img class="image" src="http://farm3.staticflickr.com/2340/2421926504_d8509d0a98_z.jpg" />
<img class="image" src="http://farm1.staticflickr.com/197/503792921_fedf8ba47e_z.jpg" />
<img class="image" src="http://farm2.staticflickr.com/1153/741035029_f394e11a1f_z.jpg" />
<img class="image" src="http://farm7.staticflickr.com/6213/6243090894_8b8dd862cd_z.jpg" />
<img class="image" src="http://farm2.staticflickr.com/1339/1157653249_dbcc93c158_z.jpg?zz=1" />
<img class="image" src="http://farm3.staticflickr.com/2570/4220856234_029e5b8348_z.jpg?zz=1" />
</div>
```

Comment: Hmm this forces the client computer to shrink and arrange the item. Does this not suffer from the same problem as using a width and height in html on a very large picture? As such it could cause problems? Also this method is not supported in IE...

Comment: @Sammaye "Forces the client to arrange" Yes, that's what CSS does. That is the proper way to arrange HTML elements on a page. There are no problems caused by this.

Comment: Awesome, after adapting it to my code it works like a charm! Sadly, as @Sammaye already mentioned: Internet Explorer does not support it (tested it up to IE9). So I end up not using it. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @ThinkingStiff I am thinking of how it arranges all those images...heavy on some computers also resizing with same ratio client side for even standard images from google images did show a significant increase in FF resources, I know FF is bad at managing its resources but still...

Comment: @Sammaye That wasn't the OP's question. He just wants to "float" vertically. Who knows what size the images are?

Comment: True, still gotta think of edge cases cos he didn't specify, but +1 its a tidy solution

Comment: Best answer ever. Only bad thing about column-count is that it will work fine with images, but it will split text paragraphs over columns, anyone knows how to prevent it?

Answer (score 3):

[jQuery Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/) from Sammaye's answer *would* work - the trick is getting it to work before the content has been appended to DOM in the original order (this would be fairly trivial on an ajax website)

There is however one reason why Masonry plugin would be **overkill** - it's the variable content width. Neither on [pinterest](http://pinterest.com/) nor in the portfolio mockup would this be needed - at the same time you end up with processing overhead on the client-side, and flash of incorrectly positioned content.

Just using container `<div>` columns would be sufficient in this scenario:

```
.column {width:33.3%;float:left;/*should be clearfix instead*/}
.column .content {width:95%;margin:2.5%;float:left;}​
```

Content can then be applied to correct columns either server-side (getting image height&width is trivial, just balance how dynamic it has to be) or on the client-side w/ajax before appending content

[Fiddled](http://jsfiddle.net/ovfiddle/uj4ku/)

Comment: +1 nice hack but only works in terms of looks when all items in that colum are the same width. Allowing the user to reorder the items in the page could break this functionality

Comment: As an extra caveat this could be defeated by data sort (i.e. from a db) so gotta client sort on image width and height ratio (unless that is stored in DB previously...which could work) to get this to work well.

Comment: @Sammaye: that's the kind of logic which would be suitable for server-side, but I question how dynamic it should be (i.e. you don't want to iterate over the same files during every page request) - maybe arrange once based on the directory content hash or something and recalculate every time items are added/removed.

Comment: +1 While I think `column-count` is the correct semantic way to do this (this method makes it difficult to switch layouts for mobile devices, for example), I learned about placekitten.com from this answer!! I wish I could +2.

Comment: @ThinkingStiff: css3 columns is indeed the correct approach, but its support matrix is still rather dissatisfying. As for mobile devices you could switch to a *one* column layout by using media queries to adjust the `.column` style so that they take up full container width below a certain resolution

Comment: @o.v. Agreed. And you could even fiddle with this and make column 2 push below column 1 on a small device.